# Validation on angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am receiving data into my my `$scope` as an object that contains various details of a client. I have the following models

```
client.name
client.email
client.programme
```

In my function I wish to ensure that every key has a value and nothing is left undefined.

I thought I could use `||` so go through each one and check for undefined within an if statement however this does not work.

for example:

```
$scope.addClient = function(newClient) {

console.log(newClient);

  if(!newClient.name ||!newClient.email) {
  $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',
     {"message" : "You must enter some client name"} 
    );
  };

...performing other functions...

}
```

Secondly I would like to use a variable in the error message so that I can tailor it to the value that is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you did not attach  $scope to variable.

use this

```
    $scope.addClient = function(newClient) {

    if(!newClient){ 
       $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',
         {"message" : "You must enter some client name"});
    }

    else if(!$scope.newClient.name || !scope.newClient.email) {
      $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',{"message" : "You must enter some client name" });
     }
  }
```

or

```
$scope.addClient = function(newClient) {

     if(newClient && (!$scope.newClient.name || !scope.newClient.email) || !newClient ){ 
               $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',
                 {"message" : "You must enter some client name"});
            }

          }
```

Comment: I think event propagation is not working.replace $emit to $broadcast.

Comment: I just get an error on `!newClient.name` cannot read property of undefined

Comment: It mean that newClient is not define.please console in function and see , is it logs?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do... newClient will be undefined unless I enter something into the input.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do this:

```
    if(!client){ 
       $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',
         {"message" : "You must enter a client name"});
    }

    else if(client.name === undefined) {
      $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',{"message" : "You must enter a client name" });
     }

    else if(client.email === undefined ) {
      $rootScope.$emit('errorEvent',{"message" : "You must enter a client email" });
     }

    else { 

REST OF FUNCTION

}
```

Happy to receive constructive criticism / options to reduce this code...